# modify a template PDF using iTextSharp server side

Tags: itext

So I'm brand spanking new to iTextSharp and I know I have quite a bit of reading ahead of me but in an attempt to shave a bunch of time off a relatively trivial task I thought I reach out the stack brain-trust.

I have a very simple goal: Starting with a template pdf, I need to create new pdf with a few of the characters changed. We're talking single characters on each page. I don't need a detailed answer complete with code (although that'd be awesome) so much as a general list of tools and api's I'm going to need.

The data I need will already be in a db which I could output to xml files if need be.

So far it looks like my template will need the "editable" characters tagged somehow (not sure how to do that yet) and using PDFStamper I can modify the copy. Is that the right path or is there a better way?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Your seemingly easy task may be very difficult after all. If, e.g., the font used for your character is embedded as a subset consisting of the used characters only, the replacement may not be in that subset and, therefore, cannot replace unless you do major font changes...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a better way to do this? I really just need to pointed in the right direction so I can cross those nasty little bridges when I come to them. I can't be the first person with this need. It's a 40 page pdf and I need to modify some characters based on the results from a web form. Everything is done except for this.

Comment: Having to manipulate the text content of a PDF is always asking for trouble. Depending on the given PDF it can be feasible,but for generic PDFs it can be impossible. That being said, if you only have one PDF to manipulate or only similarly created ones, please supply a sample for inspection.  And describe for that sample a sample replacement.

Comment: Is the template Generation under your control? In that case, using AcroForm Form fields would be a much better alternative.

Comment: As you're brand spanking new to iText(Sharp), you should read at least one chapter from the book about iText(Sharp): http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: The client should be supplying the pdf today. I have CS6 so I should be able to extract/replace or modify it as needed to make it friendly for iTextSharp. I actually purchased your book yesterday but thanks for the link. I understand much better the nature of PDF's vs typical text documents but still not clear on why simply replacing a "0" with a "3" is a big deal. I'll look at AcroForm's, that might be the ticket.

Comment: *still not clear on why simply replacing a "0" with a "3" is a big deal* - it *can* be a big deal if the font in question is embedded as a subset but this subset does not contain the glyph for "3", or if you do not know how to map binary information to characters in order to recognize the "0" to replace. But there also are many documents out there without such complications. Furthermore replacing an 'i' by a 'M' in a proportional font can be quite a problem due to the different widths of the glyphs...